# Unresolved compilation: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement JDBC Java

Tags: java

My String for a URL to connect to my database is as follows

```
String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://cvdserver07\\sql2005r2:3333;databaseName=YES_dev;integratedSecurity=true"
```

the server is called cvdserver07\sql2005r2 and the port is 3333. The database name is YES_dev.
It is not ran on the local host and the integratedSecurity=true is me trying to get windows authentication to work. I keep getting this error

Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just add ; at the end of the line.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your connection string. Statements in Java need to end with a `;`.

Comment: Add ; after your last statement: ....Security=true";

Comment: You are missing `;` at the end of statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add ; at the end of the line.

```
String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://cvdserver07\\sql2005r2:3333;databaseName=YES_dev;integratedSecurity=true";
```

Comment: I'm a dumbo. Thank you very much. I read over it like 15 times and missed that.

Comment: Happens to everyone once in a while :-)